# What is meant by [if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )]

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently building a WordPress Theme from scratch, as a means to 'learn on the job'.  I have moderate experience with backend work, though I have been heavily reliant of PageBuilders in the past.  I now wish to create a Theme without any Pagebuilders as a means to increase its Load Speed etc.

For now, I am currently looking at security for website files and came across the following term:

```
<?php 
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }
?>
```

I am of the understanding that this would prevent direct access to the web files.  I am not entirely sure what is meant by this.  For example, I could still access the file(s) via FTP, through the Server and via the WordPress Dashboard.  Is there some other direct access that this prevents?  Maybe preventing access via WordPress Plugins etc?

With this in mind, would I be right to assume that the above code should be placed on every file within the theme as standard?  Would there be any exceptions?

Any further explanation on this, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not jump to conclusions just because of recognizing some word. _Think_ about what the code actually says. That is not more then: exit, if the costant `ABSPATH` has _not_ been defined. Not more. Whether that does any good in security questions depends on a whole lot of other details. Certainly you do _not_ want to blindly copy some code snippet you found somewhere.

Comment: When you go to a URL via Wordpress, you are accessing its `index.php` file.  This file sets the constant `ABSPATH` (to the path where it's located).  The check you see makes sure you are accessing the page via `index.php` and not trying to browse to that specific file *directly*.  Such as trying to access `http://example.com/wp-content/your_file.php` (I'm not sure how wordpress stores its files, just an example)

Comment: There certainly are better (more robust) means to prevent accessing arbitrary files in some web installation than script internal constants. Such protection should be done on http server level.

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies.  This is still an area of further learning for myself.  Would I be right in thinking that if I created a series of conditional logic (if statements) on the `index.php` file loading various templates, that without the code, people will be able to go to the templates directly but with the code, they will not be able to go to the file directly in the browser?

Comment: @arkascha, why not use this script in addition to having security done on the http server level. Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: @Ben Nothing against using such lines, but I doubt that this is a good approach. It will offer a false sense of security since it apparently fixes security issues "a bit" which is a dangerous thing. Either you fix some issue or you don't. If you want to fix it then check what and where is the best approach for that and do your job. But this "a bit here, a tiny bit there" habit I often see sends chills down my back ;-)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It prevent public user to directly access your .php files through URL. Because if your file contains some I/O operations it can eventually be triggered (by an attacker) and this might cause unexpected behavior.

So, Using the snippets can prevent access from your files (directly) and ensures that your Theme files will be executed within the WordPress environment only.

**Usage:**

1. It can be placed at the top of any of your PHP files (theme & plugin)
2. It can be placed at the top of your wp-config.php

Hope it helps

Comment: @devsam247 Thanks for your answer.  Would I be right in thinking then that the conditional logic in my question is effectively saying: 
`If this file is accessed directly in the URL, do not load the rest of the file's content in the browser.  If file is accessed within the WordPress Environment, continue to load the file's content.`

Comment: Searched and found this topic because I noticed that this line of code is missing from every single functions.php file of main themes that come with WordPress. Do you know why is that?

Comment: @fat_mike Well, I can't be specific as to the reason why the code is missing, however, there are other ways to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 15):

`ABSPATH` is a [PHP constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) defined by WordPress at the **bottom** of `wp-config.php`:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

As you can see on the comment block above, **WordPress does not recommend to modify these lines of code** - probably because many plugins and themes rely on `ABSPATH` to verify if their PHP files are being executed within the WordPress environment.

If you use this snippet at the top of your `wp-config.php` file, you will terminate the execution of the `wp-config.php`, because `ABSPATH` has not been defined yet at that point. And other files that depend on `wp-config.php` will fail (i.e. you will break your website).

`if ( ! defined( 'MY_CONSTANT' ) ) { exit; }` is a snippet widely used by PHP files of plugins and themes **only by convention**. In theory, it means you can add your own constant at the bottom of your `wp-config.php`, and you will get the same practical result.

Your `wp-config.php`:

```
if ( !defined('MY_CONSTANT') )
    define('MY_CONSTANT', 'fool');
```

Your theme or plugin file:

```
<?php 
    if ( ! defined( 'MY_CONSTANT' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }
```

**More Info**

Defining a constant in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php

PHP magic constants: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: This answer dangerously off-base. It's not just "recommended" that `ABSPATH` not be modified in wp-config - and that's not simply because "many plugins and themes" rely on it. It's because it contains the absolute path to WP, which WP core uses for its own file includes!! It's not used "only by convention." It's a critical constant in WP itself.

Comment: @butlerblog 
1. The information that "it contains the absolute path to WP" is already commented out by default in the "config.php" file (please see the code I've posted above). 2. Yes, "ABSPATH" is a critical WP constant. 
Thanks for your comment.