# Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "ABSPATH"

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i tried to load my website then i got a database connection error, then i check the server side and got this error;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "ABSPATH" in /home1/uwfjfnp1/public_html/my-site-url/wp-admin/index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home1/uwfjfnp1/public_html/my-site-url/wp-admin/index.php on line 13
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l6ES.png)

i was expecting a wordpress dashboard on the index page so i could install my theme but instead i got an error in database connection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55305474/5300921 shows it can be defined if not defined already

Comment: Yeah I didn’t really get what they were saying please explain better thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe not recommended (to change), but this should be in your wp-config.php file:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```